# config web service from code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, web-services, mobile

I am creating a windows mobile 6 application which will consume a web service (.asmx) for different clients. 
As I know, I will need to manually “Add Web Reference”; then I will be able to call those functions.
Is it possible to configure web reference as a variable from code behind? 
That way I can keep the url of web service in a text file. For different client, I just need to edit that text file instead of recompile that application again.

Comment: can't be dont generally speaking but you can find a work around here http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/39138d08-aa08-4c0c-9a58-0eb81a672f54 let me know if this helps

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to add the Web Reference at design time.

At runtime, you can modify the URL of your target web service using the `Url` property. Here's an example of pulling the target URL from the app.config:

```
var ws = new MyWebService();
ws.Url = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SomeUrl"].ToString();
```

The only catch here is that the WSDLs of the design-time and run-time services must match.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just add something like :

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="WebReference" value="URLofASMX"/>
...
```

then call it by :

```
string URL = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WebReference"].ToString();
```

You'll need to possibly add a new reference to `System.Configuration` to the project if you can't access `ConfigurationManager` just by including `System.Configuration`.

Comment: i've added System.Configuration into the project but the name space was not found